# flutter The method 'File.create' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'File.create'

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging

When I try to run my Flutter project, I get errors like:

> ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-6.1.2/lib/src/interface/file.dart:15:16: Error: The method 'File.create' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'File.create'. Future create({bool recursive = false});

Running `flutter clean` and `flutter upgrade` didn't help.  What's wrong?  How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you include any flutter dependencies?

Comment: please post the contents of your pubspec.yaml

Comment: What version of Flutter are you running? What is the output of `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: seems the file package is outdated, use  flutter pub outdated  command to check it, then use  flutter pub upgrade command to update your packages.

Comment: Me too. I tried many commands start with flutter, like flutter doctor -v, and they always give the same output.

Answer (score 177):

### Solution 1:

I kept getting the same error, But I solved it adding by adding
`file: ^6.1.4` in my dependencies

If you are having the same problem. Make sure you have the latest [file](https://pub.dev/packages/file) dependency.

### Solution 2:

If `file` wasn't one of your dependency. Just run the below command to upgrade transitive dependencies

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

This will update all packages to latest compatible versions. And `file` may be updated as well to latest version.

Comment: Same for me after upgrade to Flutter 3.7 ... idk why i have to add a dependency, maybe another dependency requires this one. But adding this one solve my problem

Comment: I added then removed the dependency which updated my local cache and now seems to work fine.

Comment: Upgrading pub fixed the issue, thanks mate!

Comment: Adding `file: ^6.1.4` worked for me. Dope!

Comment: Solution 2 worked for me, since I didn't have file in my pubspec.yaml file.

Answer (score 40):

I think the problem is caused by an outdated reference to [file](https://pub.dev/packages/file) dependency. See this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/110827).

For fix this, on the project or library folder run:

```
dart pub upgrade
```

This command will upgrade your dependencies and the problem will be solved without adding the reference to latest version of [file](https://pub.dev/packages/file) dependency.

Answer (score 30):

For me the packages in my `pubspec.yaml` were all up to date, but the following fixed it:

1. Delete `pubspec.lock`.
2. Run `flutter pub get` again.

Answer (score 12):

I am also getting this issue after upgrading to the latest version v3.7.

I solved the issue by doing the following thing:

**First, run this command:**

```
flutter clean
```

**after this, run the pub get to get the dependencies and run this command :**

```
dart pub upgrade
```

it will fix the project or library version prob for file

Answer (score 7):

just follow these steps:

1. **flutter clean**
2. **dart pub upgrade**

check for updated pub versions and add them into pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 6):

I just ran in to this issue and I was on flutter's master channel. I switched back to stable (`flutter channel stable`) and everything works fine.

Answer (score 4):

You need to upgrade your dependencies to latest versions:

First you can run `flutter pub upgrade` in your terminal.
Secondly you can add latest packages from pub dev `https://pub.dev/`

Answer (score 4):

In the terminal, give the commands

1. flutter pub outdated
2. flutter pub upgrade
   Run the application, it should work.

Answer (score 3):

i solved it by adding file: ^6.1.4 to my pubspec i dont know why this is needed in dependenccies but when i added it worked
this error occured to me when i was trying to update my flutter and packages
but error thrown was of transitive dependencies i guess when u defin in dependencies it over rides the transitive one
but it worked for me
but after wards once project ran i removed the file dependencie from my punspec did a flutter clean and a pub get again and ran the project again it worked without any problem

Answer (score 1):

**This error might occur if you are using a version of Dart that is different from the one used by the Flutter SDK. To resolve this error, try updating your Dart version by running the following command in your terminal:**

```
dart pub global activate dart_style
```

if it doesn't work try this

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

**In My Case these commands worked**
In terminal

1. flutter pub add file
2. flutter pub get

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting this issue then that means you have to update these things:

- gradle update from both files wrapper/ and build grade
- flutter clean
- flutter pub updgrade
- upgrade some of the dependencies manually if you still finds issue e.g(firebase core, fireabase storage)
- kotlin_version from 1.6.10 to 20
  i hope after that things will work out