# Flutter: Error: The method 'File.create' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'File.create'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-6.1.2/lib/src/interface/file.dart:15:16: Error: The method 'File.create' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'File.create'.
Future create({bool recursive = false});

org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/io/file.dart:232:16: Context: This is the overridden method ('create').
Future create({bool recursive = false, bool exclusive = false});
^

../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-6.1.2/lib/src/interface/file.dart:15:16: Error: The method 'File.create' doesn't have the named parameter 'exclusive' of overridden method 'File.create'.
Future create({bool recursive = false});
^

org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/io/file.dart:232:16: Context: This is the overridden method ('create').
Future create({bool recursive = false, bool exclusive = false});
^

../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-6.1.2/lib/src/forwarding/forwarding_file.dart:22:8: Error: The method 'ForwardingFile.createSync' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'File.createSync'.
void createSync({bool recursive = false}) =>
^

org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/io/file.dart:248:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('createSync').
void createSync({bool recursive = false, bool exclusive = false});
^

../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-6.1.2/lib/src/forwarding/forwarding_file.dart:22:8: Error: The method 'ForwardingFile.createSync' doesn't have the named parameter 'exclusive' of overridden method 'File.createSync'.
void createSync({bool recursive = false}) =>
^

org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/io/file.dart:248:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('createSync').
void createSync({bool recursive = false, bool exclusive = false});
^

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/myuser/Documents/Softwere/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1151
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/Users/myuser/Documents/Softwere/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I have not use the "file" plugin in my project.

Plugins used in my project:

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  get: ^4.6.5
  http: ^0.13.5
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.17
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.6.1
  intl_phone_field: ^3.1.0
  pin_code_fields: ^7.4.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  intl: ^0.18.0
  flutter_multi_formatter: ^2.10.2
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.6+1
 image_cropper: ^3.0.1
 cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
 country_codes: ^2.2.0
 firebase_messaging: ^14.0.3
cloud_firestore: ^4.0.3
firebase_core: ^2.1.1
google_sign_in: ^5.4.2
google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.1
geolocator: ^9.0.2
geocoding: ^2.0.5
flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0
flutter_facebook_auth: ^4.4.1+1
draggable_fab: ^0.1.4
google_place: ^0.4.7
flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
dotted_border: ^2.0.0+3
flutter_local_notifications: ^12.0.3
webview_flutter: ^3.0.4
path_provider: ^2.0.12
decimal: ^2.3.2
file_picker: ^5.2.5
package_info_plus: ^3.0.3
sign_in_with_apple: ^4.1.0
flutter_stripe: ^6.0.0
flutter_svg: ^2.0.1
upgrader: ^5.0.0
dual_screen: ^1.0.3
```

Comment: This is link is worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75325821/11124178