# error in flutter due to lack of programs or incompatibility

Tags: flutter, dart

good afternoon. First of all, before coming here, I investigated on my own, but I'm still stuck. You see, we have a project in which the other developer ran and it worked for him. But when I try I get incompatibility errors and also another error that I don't understand where it says that there are methods in that library that have fewer arguments with names than overridden methods. But I imagine that it must be something that is not installed, I don't know. Is it a matter of missing something to install or what is it? Thank you. here the error in console.

```
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-6.1.2/lib/src/interface/file.dart:15:16: Error: The method
'File.create' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'File.create'.
  Future<File> create({bool recursive = false});
               ^
org-dartlang-sdk:///dart-sdk/lib/io/file.dart: Context: This is the overridden method ('create').
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-6.1.2/lib/src/interface/file.dart:15:16: Error: The method
'File.create' doesn't have the named parameter 'exclusive' of overridden method 'File.create'.
  Future<File> create({bool recursive = false});
               ^
org-dartlang-sdk:///dart-sdk/lib/io/file.dart: Context: This is the overridden method ('create').
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-6.1.2/lib/src/forwarding/forwarding_file.dart:22:8: Error: The method
'ForwardingFile.createSync' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'File.createSync'.
  void createSync({bool recursive = false}) =>
       ^
org-dartlang-sdk:///dart-sdk/lib/io/file.dart: Context: This is the overridden method ('createSync').
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-6.1.2/lib/src/forwarding/forwarding_file.dart:22:8: Error: The method
'ForwardingFile.createSync' doesn't have the named parameter 'exclusive' of overridden method 'File.createSync'.
  void createSync({bool recursive = false}) =>
       ^
org-dartlang-sdk:///dart-sdk/lib/io/file.dart: Context: This is the overridden method ('createSync').
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-6.1.2/lib/src/backends/memory/memory_file.dart:57:8: Error: The method
'MemoryFile.createSync' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'File.createSync'.
  void createSync({bool recursive = false}) {
       ^
org-dartlang-sdk:///dart-sdk/lib/io/file.dart: Context: This is the overridden method ('createSync').
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-6.1.2/lib/src/backends/memory/memory_file.dart:57:8: Error: The method
'MemoryFile.createSync' doesn't have the named parameter 'exclusive' of overridden method 'File.createSync'.
  void createSync({bool recursive = false}) {
       ^
org-dartlang-sdk:///dart-sdk/lib/io/file.dart: Context: This is the overridden method ('createSync').
```

then run flutter doctor and got the following:

```
flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.3, on Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.19045.2728], locale es-CO)
    • Flutter version 3.7.3 on channel stable at C:\Users\USER\Downloads\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 9944297138 (4 months ago), 2023-02-08 15:46:04 -0800
    • Engine revision 248290d6d5
    • Dart version 2.19.2
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[X] Windows Version (Unable to confirm if installed Windows version is 10 or greater)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33-ext4, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.17\bin\java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.17+10-LTS-269)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted. To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[√] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.58.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.19045.2728]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 111.0.5563.146
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 111.0.1661.54

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.
```

Comment: Have you try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73561012/flutter-the-method-file-create-has-fewer-named-arguments-than-those-of-overrid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to upgrade plugin version to 6.1.3 or above for `file`

In the changelog, there seems to be some issue which they have fixed which you are getting right now.

https://pub.dev/packages/file/changelog

Look for 6.1.3 changelog item.